# Creating a simpler, domain-specific language by restricting the Javascript support in Google's V8?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

Is it possible to create a simpler language by restricting the Javascript support in Google's V8?  I'd like to embed the V8 engine in my own tool to run dynamic scripts, and like the idea of V8 precomiling the source for speed. However I need to drastically restrict what is possible within the language.

That means no dynamic allocation of data containers (e.g. arrays), no imported libraries, no recursion, no threads. It's more similar in philosophy to Renderman Shading Language than a general purpose language. The 'new' language is thus much simpler, and I'm only considering JS due to familiar syntax and the fact there's a good 'compiler' already (V8). I might also want it to run script code from within Chrome's native code (NaCl) environment, which Google seems to be working to support in V8.

How easy is it to redefine the JS 'grammar', or whatever other code define the language?

My other option is to create a new compiled language from scratch (maybe using LLVM stuff).

Answer (score 0):

For all the features restriction you want, you would need to carry out a major surgery on V8 as V8 is never designed for such a radical modification.

An alternative solution is to *invent* a JavaScript-like language (with all the limitations you can impose) and *compile* it into normal JavaScript which then you can run with V8 (or any other JavaScript engine, for that matter). Well-known examples of such an approach are GWT (from Java), Dart, and TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at squirrel language :
http://squirrel-lang.org
from description overview : 
"both compiler and virtual machine fit together in about 7k lines of C++ code and add only around 100kb-150kb the executable size."

Enjoy!